# simple jquery pagination (content slider)

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I want to make content slider where content will change on cliking the pagination at bottom like this [image]

I have made written HTML/CSS for this

http://jsfiddle.net/jitendravyas/Bbuyu/6/

Which jquery plugin you would prefer to use with it. I have tried some but they have different type of mark-up and I don't want to change my mark-up

**HTML**

```
<div class="season-box">
          <div class="slide-outer nopad">
            <ul id="slide-box">

               <!--  slide 1 -->
              <li> <img src="http://lorempixel.com/264/139" alt="season">
                <h5>Lorem Ipsum</h5>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum are group of islands and a Union Territory located in Indian Ocean. The capital of the territory is Port Blair, located in a small island in Andaman...</p>
                <ul class="list">
                  <li class="icon1"><strong>1200</strong> onwards&gt;</li>
                  <li class="icon2"><strong>129</strong> hotels</li>
                  <li class="icon3"><strong>24</strong>things to do | Most popular: Scuba diving</li>
                </ul>
              </li>

                <!--  slide 2 -->
              <li> <img src="http://lorempixel.com/264/139" alt="season">
                <h5Lorem Ipsum Islands</h5>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum are group of islands and a Union Territory located in Indian Ocean. The capital of the territory is Port Blair, located in a small island in Andaman...</p>
                <ul class="list">
                  <li class="icon1"><strong>1200</strong> onwards</li>
                  <li class="icon2"><strong>129</strong> hotels</li>
                  <li class="icon3"><strong>24</strong> things to do | Most popular: Scuba diving</li>
                </ul>
              </li>

                     <!--  slide 3 -->
              <li> <img src="http://lorempixel.com/264/139" alt="season">
                <h5>Andaman Nicobar Islands</h5>
                <p>Andaman &amp; Nicobar Islands are group of islands and a Union Territory located in Indian Ocean. The capital of the territory is Port Blair, located in a small island in Andaman...</p>
                <ul class="list">
                  <li class="icon1"><strong>1200</strong> onwards</li>
                  <li class="icon2"><strong>129</strong> hotels</li>
                  <li class="icon3"><strong>24</strong> things to do | Most popular: Scuba diving</li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>


              <!--  Pagination -->
            <div class="pager">
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="active">1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
              </ul>
          </div>
        </div>​
```

**CSS**

```
.season-box {
    color:#666;
    font-size:14px;
    margin:0 0 40px 0;
    width:300px
}
.slide-outer {
    background:#f8f8f8;
    padding:20px 0 15px 18px;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:15px 0 20px 0;
}
.nopad {
    padding:20px 0 15px 0 !important;
}
#slide-box {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 16px 18px;
  width: 264px;
  height: 350px;
  position: relative;
  li {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background: #F8F8F8;
    p {
      margin: 0 0 14px 0; } }
}

.pager {
    text-align:right;
    position:relative;
    z-index:999999;
    margin:0 18px 0 0;
}
.pager ul {
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    display:inline-block;
}

.pager ul li {
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0 2px 0 0;
}
.pager ul li a {
    border:1px solid #d26043;
    line-height:15px;
    background:blue;
    color:#fff;
    display:block;
    width:15px;
    height:15px;
    text-align:center;
}
.pager ul li a:hover, .pager ul li a.active {
    color:#d26043;
    background:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
}


*+ html .pager ul {
    display:inline;
}
*+ html .pager ul li {
    display:inline;
    margin:0 6px 0 0;
}

.pager .more {
    display:inline-block;
    color:blue;
    font-size:11px;
}
*+ html .pager .more {
    display:inline;
}
.season-box h5 {
    margin:0 0 12px 0;
    color:#58a86a;
    font-size:14px;
}
.season-box h2 {
    margin:0 0 5px 0!important;
}
.season-box li img, .season-box img {
    margin:0 0 13px 0;
}
.list {
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    width:264px;
}
.list li {
    padding:0 0 0 32px;
    margin:0 0 12px 0;
    position:static !important;
    font-size:14px;
}​
```

Comment: without rewriting your code, you will have to do a custom solution on your own ;-) there are many slider and pagination plugins out there just google it.

Answer (score 3):

You can make the slider by yourself. Try this code: http://jsfiddle.net/Bbuyu/16/

The only changes that I have done are giving the li of the slide-box an id to call them with jquery, then adding an onclick event to the buttons. Also have deleted the "a href" tags because they were useless.

If you want to use some kind of animation in the slide, you can search for animations in the jquery guide, there are lots, but, personally, I'd try to be very minimalystic with them.

Comment: +1 thanks. but you are using `$('ul#slide-box li').hide();` which hiding all `li` inside `li`

Comment: Sorry, didn't saw the additional li in the code: http://jsfiddle.net/Bbuyu/18/ This should work fine. Only changed the first hide to affect only the ul#slide-box direct children.

Comment: Is this the right way to add animation  `$("ul#slide-box>li").fadeIn("slow");`

Comment: Great help. Thanks very much for your time. But is there any way to do without giving id's to each li.?